# Adding javascript and css in my wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm adding javascript and css to my wordpress theme. I had a hard time but at the moment is working fine. I just want you to take a look to it to see if I'm doing it the right way. This is my first wordpress theme and finally I'm learning how to use the codex. I'm adding `style.css`, `bootstrap.min.css`, `jquery.min.js`, `bootstrap.min.js` and `google.fonts`.

```
/**
 * Register Lato Google font for rsdonations
 */
function rsdonations_font_url() {
    $font_url = '';
    /*
     * Translators: If there are characters in your language that are not supported
     * by Lato, translate this to 'off'. Do not translate into your own language.
     */
    if ( 'off' !== _x( 'on', 'Lato font: on or off', 'rsdonations' ) ) {
        $font_url = add_query_arg( 'family', urlencode( 'Lato:300' ), "//fonts.googleapis.com/css" );
    }

    return $font_url;
}

/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles for the front end.
 */
function wpt_register_js() {
    // Core bootstrap javascript.
    wp_register_script('bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '2013-11-14', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap.min');

    // Add Lato font, used in the main stylesheet.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'rsdonations-lato', rsdonations_font_url(), array(), null );

    // Core bootstrap stylesheet.
    wp_register_style( 'bootstrap.min', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap.min');

    // Loads our main stylesheet.
    wp_register_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style('style');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpt_register_js' );
```

Comment: make sure you deregister the built-in jquery that comes with wordpress... that way you avoid jquery version collisions and no need to load two of the same libraries

Comment: After a little change I decided to use wordpress's to avoid comflicts. Thanks.

Comment: your setup looks good by the way, you can also register your scripts `wp_register_script` and then use `wp_enqueue_scripts` but your method works well..

Comment: @DavidChase Humm, and what's the difference between `wp_register_script` and `wp_register_scripts`?

Comment: do you mean `wp_register_script` vs `wp_enqueue_scripts` ?

Comment: @DavidChase sorry I meant `wp_register_scripts` vs `wp_register_script` because I was using `wp_register_script` but when addded the `s` to it I got an error.

Comment: `wp_register_scripts` i believe is not a function thats why you got an error :)